# Getting error while executing PowerShell script from a .bat file

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

I have one PowerShell script `test.ps1` and I am trying to execute it from a test.bat file. My batch file contains:

```
@echo off
Powershell.exe -File D:\Testfolder\testsubfolder\test.ps1
pause
```

And I am getting the error:

> '■@' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Can someone point out what change I should make to run it correctly?

Comment: Can you post the code please

Comment: This looks like an encoding problem. To debug it, you should consider [creating a MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Include a hexdump of the first couple bytes of the script file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Rename your batch file to a .txt format
2. Open the file in Notepad
3. Change the Encoding to ANSI using the Save As method (encoding will be at the bottom of the save file window)
4. Save the file again and rename it back to a .bat format

Comment: it worked @Random206, actually i copied the old bat file and updated the script inside it, when i created new file as you suggested it worked. thank you

Comment: No problems, happy to help.